# Is there any chance of a new tag: Pure-PHP

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

While I love answering questions about PHP I find it harder and harder to find a purely PHP question due to the immense number of frameworks out there.
A new tag, say pure-php could be set up to answer specifically base PHP questions only.

I'm sure I'm not the only person who encounters this difficulty in location questions specific to my skill set so please consider it.

Comment: Questions only tagged with [tag:php] are supposed to be only about PHP. If they use a framework, the according tag needs to be added.

Comment: Well I'm surprised at the down votes! Maybe instructions for searching questions with only the PHP tag would be useful to me and others.

Comment: [Downvotes are slightly different on meta...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  Here they probably mean that people disagree with your post.  It has nothing to do with the quality of the post (in this case at least)...

Comment: Thanks for the update on votes :)

Comment: +1 for some unicorn points to show support for asking the question and, I presume, being open to the responses. Not to signify agreement with the proposal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming 'correct' usage of tags, such a tag is completely unnecessary.

With correct tag usage, you can simply exclude from your view the tags for frameworks about which you do not wish to answer questions. The presence of a [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag alone will be your indicator.

Of course, tag usage is always imperfect. That's something you can fix as you come across questions tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php) only; you could add on the tags for frameworks that also apply, so future 'purists' won't see the 'extra' stuff.

Comment: How can I exclude tags for frameworks I don't want to view?

Comment: From the main page, look on the right for the 'ignored tags' box.

Answer (score 5):

No... I don't think so. The [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag is enough for a question about PHP as a language. There's no need for another tag to say that you're looking for non-framework answers. Besides, if a framework is involved in a question, the question will typically have the framework tag along with the language tag.

In fact, that would make [pure-php](/questions/tagged/pure-php) a [meta-tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags), and if we had one for PHP we would need one for other languages, and it'll spin out of control. We have enough tags for frameworks; we don't need one for the exclusion of frameworks which is just as easily expressed as... not having any framework tags at all.